# Irregular rows but regular columns with Twitter-Bootstrap 3

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to achieve a layout where there are 4 columns in which content is in boxes that are capable of stacking vertically. This means that there are no regular rows (each content box can be different height), only regular columns (content boxes have always the same width).

The problem is - I have no idea how to do it via PHP loops. That's because I have to put the first post into the first column, the second post into the second column, third one into column nr 3, the fourth one into column nr 4 and then the 5th post goes AGAIN into column 1, etc.

So there are four columns and twenty posts, the newest posts are at the top and the oldest ones are at the bottom.

Here's a screenshot of what I already have so that you see the irregular rows and regular columns concept:

[image: Example]

As requested, my code:

```
$counter = 0;
for($cols = 0; $cols < 4; $cols++) {
?>

<!-- COLUMN NR <?php echo $cols; ?> -->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 post_box">             
<?php
foreach ($post_list as $p) {
    $the_post = get_post($p);
    $the_title = $the_post->post_title;
    $the_content = $the_post->post_content;

    if($counter == (0 + $cols) || $counter == (4 + $cols) || $counter == (8 + $cols) || $counter == (12 + $cols) || $counter == (16 + $cols) ) {
    ?>
    <!-- POST NR <?php echo $counter; ?> WITH ID <?php echo $p; ?> -->
    <div class="post_container">
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($the_post->ID); ?>">
        <div class="row postbox_title">
            <div class="col-xs-12 title_col">
            <h2><?php echo $the_title; ?></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row postbox_content">
            <div class="col-xs-12 content_col">
                <div class="post_content">
                    <?php echo '<p>'.$the_content.'</p>'; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>                        
    </div>
    <?php
    }           
    $counter++;
}
?>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Here's a screenshot of my code to make it more readable:
http://scr.hu/5z5a/icinl

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: Please include your code so there's something to go on that we might figure out what you may be doing wrong, thus to guide you towards the right answer.

Comment: Screenshots are nice, code is actually helpful, so try to include that.

Comment: You want something like http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Thank you, @JayBlanchard - I've editted my post, now the code is there, although this is the not-working one (obviously).

Comment: And @ceejayoz - I need a solution that works without using any additional libraries, Bootstrap should be enough, if it's possible of course.

Comment: You can divide the posts in 4 arrays, say col1, col2, col3, and col4. Then you can have one foreach for every array.

Comment: @Choma, you're the closest to the thing I want to do, but is there a possibility to reduce code repetition? Typing 4 almost identical foreach statements is not very optimal and my for+foreach combination gives me wrong results.

Comment: @Pe-Ter, Check my answer... It may have errors since I don't have an environment for testing in this moment :-/

Comment: @Choma Sure, I will check it in my code as soon as I am able to and I will select it as the correct answer if it works :). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the posts into 4 arrays, and then use a foreach to create the cols. Something like (pseudocode):

```
// one foreach to divide posts
$col = 1;
foreach($posts as $post) {
    $cols[$col][] = $post;
    $col = $col == 4 ? 1 : $col+1;
}
// then, another foreach for the html
foreach($cols as $col) {
    // open col div
    foreach($col as $post) {
        // print post
    }
    // close col div
}
```

You can see the code output [here](http://3v4l.org/uQO2f).

Answer (score 0):

It's **Masonry** css you are looking for, you can do it with only html and css.

```
#CSS:
.masonry { /* Masonry container */
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    column-gap: 1em;
}

.item { /* Masonry bricks or child elements */
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    width: 100%;
}


#HTML:   
<div class="masonry">
   <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
   <div class="item">Neque, vitae, fugiat, libero corrupti officiis sint facilis tempora quidem repudiandae praesentium odit similique adipisci aut.</div>
   <div class="item">Incidunt sit unde minima in nostrum?</div>
   <div class="item">Ducimus, voluptates, modi, delectus animi maiores consequuntur repellat quisquam fugiat eum possimus enim culpa totam praesentium magni quae!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible for me to keep the bootstrap columns there or shall I remove them and substitute them with Masontry classes fully?

Comment: This code is enough, add your title and content inside <div class="item">.

Save Css code to new file and import it in your html or php to not change Bootstrap files.

@ceejayoz : I believe there is a jQuery plugin for older IE browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to @Chorna I managed to fork his answer and fix my problem! Thank you for that :).

I loaded the posts into an array this way:

```
    switch($post_counter) {
    case 0:
    case 4:
    case 8:
    case 12:
    case 16:                            
        $col = 1;
        break;
    case 1:
    case 5:
    case 9:
    case 13:
    case 17:
        $col = 2;
        break;
    case 2:
    case 6:
    case 10:
    case 14:
    case 18:
        $col = 3;
        break;
    case 3:
    case 7:
    case 11:
    case 15:
    case 19:
        $col = 4;
        break;
}
$post_list[$col][] = get_the_ID();
$post_counter++;
```

Then I displayed them like this:

```
foreach($post_list as $post_element) {
?>
<!-- COLUMN NR <?php echo $cols; ?> -->
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 post_box">             
<?php
foreach ($post_element as $p) {
    $the_post = get_post($p);
    $the_title = $the_post->post_title;
    $the_content = $the_post->post_content;
    ?>
    <!-- POST NR <?php echo $counter; ?> WITH ID <?php echo $p; ?> -->
    <div class="post_container">
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($the_post->ID); ?>">
        <div class="row postbox_title">
            <div class="col-xs-12 title_col">
            <h2><?php echo $the_title; ?></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row postbox_content">
            <div class="col-xs-12 content_col">
                <div class="post_content">
                    <?php echo '<p>'.$the_content.'</p>'; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>                        
    </div>
    <?php
    }
```

Thank you all for your help!